# What is the best bigO time complexity for shifting and removing a head element?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Lets say I have a data structure consisting of three elements, {1,2,3}

what data structure and what time complexities would give me the best results if i wanted to only perform the following operations?

-Shifting the last element to the 'front' of the datastructure
-Removing the (now) last element

I found this page: http://essays.hexapodia.net/datastructures/ and it says a double-linked list has O(1) for some operations?

However, I need to preserve the order of the elements each time so I can do the shift. If I had {1,2,3} i would then want to shift, get 3,1,2 and then remove, leaving 3,1 and then remove, leaving 1

If I used a double linked list would my complexity be O(1)???

Comment: Removing an element that you have a *pointer* *to* is O(1) in a double-linked list. Likewise, inserting an element before or after an element you have a pointer to is O(1). Finding the element in the first place would typically be O(n).

Comment: You might want to explain a bit more of the *removing* business. Why is the first `remove` removing `2` (tail of the sequence), but the second removing `3` (which at the time is the head of the sequence)?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, removing and adding elements at both ends are O(1) in a double-linked list that keeps pointers to head and tail. Since shifting can be implemented with these two operations, it is O(1) too.

In a circularly linked list, you could even implement your own shifting operation (still O(1), but faster) by doing

```
head = tail
if (tail != null) tail = tail.prev
```

Comment: Well, if this is the case i think I have just written a powerset algorithm in O(n^3) and I keep reading the best is O(2^n).

Comment: @James T Since a power set contains 2^n elements, there is no algorithm generating it any faster. Feel free to ask for problems of your algorithm in a new question.

Comment: @James: The power set of a set with n elements has 2^n elements itself, you can't really produce such a set in less than 2^n steps.

Comment: @James T: When you start destructuring your double-linked list (as you're doing), you're definitely blending in a fair few new O(n) into the mix. Try it with more elements and see if the analysis still holds.

Comment: I believe that the pseudo code algorithm is wrong for a simple double linked list (would work in a circular double list, but in that case the condition `tail == null` would not be met except for an empty list...

Comment: @David Rodríguez Oops, you're totally right. Updating by making the list circular. I added the last line in an edit, but it's totally unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [deque](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue), which is `O(1)` for insertion or removal at either end.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion , if rotate is the only operation you want to do , then use a circular-array ( normal array where head could come after tail)

With circular you will save on 
1. Deletion
2. Insertion

All you have to do is change the head and tail pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Most implementations of a doubly linked list have a pointer to the head and the tail.  Since you want to shift the end to the front, it is trivially O(1) because you have pointers to those places.  Removing them is also trivially O(1) because its just a matter of setting the tail pointer to its previous link.

HOWEVER, if you do not have a tail pointer and the linked list is not circular, then the remove and the shift will NOT be O(1).  Be sure you check the implementation.